# Easiest way to rotate image at specific frequency

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-imaging-library

I'm looking to plot a function, then rotate it at a specific frequency (ie. 15 revolutions per second).

What would be the easiest way to do this in python?

I'm open to simply plotting the function in desmos and then rotating a PNG at a specific frequency as well.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way with matplotlib's `FuncAnimation`

```
# set up data
data = pd.DataFrame({0:np.linspace(-1,1,101)})

# function values
data[1] = data[0]**2

# rotation matrix
alpha = np.deg2rad(15)
rot_mat = np.array([[np.cos(alpha), -np.sin(alpha)],[np.sin(alpha), np.cos(alpha)]])

# set up plots
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6,6))
ln, = plt.plot([],[], 'r')

# set up animation
def init():
    ax.set_xlim(-1,1)
    ax.set_ylim(-1,1)
    return ln,

def update(frame):
    global data
    data = (rot_mat @ data.T).T
    ln.set_data(data[0], data[1])

    return ln,

# init animation
anim = FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=np.arange(100),
                    init_func=init, blit=True)

plt.plot()
```

Output:

[image]